# How to set up Spring security to authenticate signed requests?

Tags: authorization, spring-security, opensocial

Does spring support authentication of signed requests? (like those provided by open social **Signed authorization** ,i.e [open social makeRequest API](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Gadgets.io_(v0.8)))

if so, how do you configure it?

Best Regards

Yaniv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/features.html) site it looks like it does not support it. But nothing stops you from implementing it. You will have to implement custom AbstractProcessingFilter (just like there is a filter for CAS CasProcessingFilter, login form AuthenticationProcessingFilter and OpenId OpenIDAuthenticationProcessingFilter). You might also have to implement AuthenticationProvider and configure it similar to this:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
<property name="providers">
    <list>
      <ref local="myAuthenticationProvider" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: The current implementation of spring oauth now supports this